# how to get the second return value of a function in a if condition in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have a function which returns two values.
Is there a way to check the second value in a if condition?

```
local function a()
return 1 , true
end

if a()[2] == true then
print("yes")
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function returns a tuple consisting of two values: `1` and `true`
There are (at least) two ways to extract the second value of the tuple:

1. You can convert the tuple into a table and index it:

```
if ({a()})[2] == true then
```

2. You can shift the tuple (so that the second value would become the first)

```
if select(2, a()) == true then
```

Comment: The second method is preferable, as it creates no garbage table and runs in constant time (vs. the first method running in linear time).

Comment: @LMD - You're correct unless you're playing codegolf :-)